# Beginner Java Developer Netbeans/Eclipse IDE Questions

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Im working on building a java application in windows vista using the Emotiv Epoc Neuroheadset, http://emotiv.com/index.php.

I'm new to java and having a really tough time getting started. I have some examples that came with the headset I'm trying to run in either eclipse or netbeans (at this point I really don't have a preference, suggestions?)

The user manual gives these directions:

*2. Package content:  Jna.rar, Edk.java,  EmoState.java, EDkErrorCode.java
Example 1: EEGLog 
Example 2: EmoStateLog

1. Developer‘s guide: Step 1: Add the JNA library to your project.  Step 2: Add Edk.java, EmoState.java, EdkErrorCode.java to your project. The classes in these files contain methods calling the APIs from Edk.dll using JNA library. You can find more information about the conversion between data types on the JNA's homepage.*

This is all Chinese to me! Can someone explain to me exactly how to do these steps (in a way a small child who have never used eclipse or netbeans before can understand!) Somebody from the Emotiv Epoc forum gave me these directions as well:

*To see how to Java wrapper examples work you should install Eclipse and open, compile them. You put edk_utils.dll and edk.dll into System32 or the same root directory of each example as EmoStateLog, CognitivExample,... before running them.*

My problem is I dont know enough about the IDEs to run these examples. Am I supposed to make a new project then add these files? Or do I open one of the examples, then add the .dll files and the JNA library? How do you add libraries to a project? Where do I put the .dll files?

Thanks in advance! 
I know this is fairly simple stuff but its always the simple stuff thats hardest to figure out it seems!
-Eric

Comment: Tools didn't help you much without knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Based purely off of what you're saying here...

> Developer‘s guide: Step 1: Add the JNA library to your project. Step 2: Add Edk.java, EmoState.java, EdkErrorCode.java to your project. The classes in these files contain methods calling the APIs from Edk.dll using JNA library. You can find more information about the conversion between data types on the JNA's homepage.*

1. Create a new project in Eclipse.
2. Add Edk.java, Emostate.java, EdkErrorCode.java into the src folder
3. Add the JNA library into the libs folder. (Make sure the library is in the project path, otherwise Eclipse won't detect it.)

Whether or not it will compile depends on if those are the only supporting files.